# How to change MetroFramework tabs color in C#

Tags: c#, metroframework

I'm using MetroFramework in my desktop application, and I already set all themes to dark and green. But I have a problem with the `TabControl` when the second Tab is within the first one; tabs colors are changing theme to light.

[image]

How can I make it dark?

Comment: Have you set the Style of each TabPages `(collection)` into `Dark` as well?